# How to get new-style ESLint config working with pre-commit?

Tags: node.js, eslint, pre-commit-hook, pre-commit.com

I've got a project with a `.pre-commit-config.yaml` that features, among other things, the official ESLint hook. It works perfectly when using the old-style `.eslintrc.json` config, but replacing it with the new-style `eslint.config.js` causes it to fail.

The hook config looks like this:

```yaml
  - repo: https://github.com/pre-commit/mirrors-eslint
    rev: v8.51.0
    hooks:
    - id: eslint
      types: [javascript]
      additional_dependencies: [
        'globals@13.21.0',
        'eslint@8.51.0',
        '@eslint/js',
        'eslint-config-prettier@9.0.0'
      ]
```

Running `pre-commit install-hooks`, ESLint itself and the listed dependencies are seemingly installed without errors (no `~/.cache/pre-commit/pre-commit.log` gets created). I don't have ESLint globally installed.

This is the old-style `.eslintc.json` config with which everything works:

```json
{
    "env": {
      "es2022": true,
      "browser": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "eslint:recommended",
      "prettier"
    ],
    "ignorePatterns": [
      "project/static/htmx/**"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
      "sourceType": "module"
    },
    "rules": {}
}
```

However, using this `eslint.config.js` fails, even though it seems to be perfectly valid when comparing to new style config examples in the ESLint documentation:

```js
import globals from "globals";
import js from "@eslint/js";
import eslintConfigPrettier from "eslint-config-prettier";

export default [
  js.configs.recommended,
  eslintConfigPrettier,
  {
    languageOptions: {
      globals: {
        ...globals.browser,
      },
      sourceType: "module",
      ecmaVersion: 2022,
    },
  },
  {
    ignores: ["project/static/htmx/**"],
  },
];
```

This is the error when running `pre-commit run --all-files`:

```
eslint...................................................................Failed
- hook id: eslint
- exit code: 2

Oops! Something went wrong! :(

ESLint: 8.51.0

Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find package 'globals' imported from /Users/jkl/Development/foobar/eslint.config.js
Did you mean to import globals/index.js?
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:406:5)
    at packageResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:789:9)
    at moduleResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:838:20)
    at defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1043:11)
    at ModuleLoader.defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:383:12)
    at ModuleLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:352:25)
    at ModuleLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:228:38)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:85:39)
    at link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:84:36)
```

`ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND` is equally raised for the other two imports if I move them to the first line, so it's not a `globals` issue.

Despite me installing all the necessary dependencies for those three imports in `eslint.config.js` to work in the documented way, they cannot be found. So something's off, and the fact that the hook works fine with the old-style config, without changing `.pre-commit-config.yaml` at all, makes me think that either a) I'm missing some crucial bit of configuration, or b) the ESLint hook just plain doesn't support the new-style config for some reason, or c) ESLint itself has some sort of incompatibility with the combination of the new config and the way pre-commit installs it.

I'm not a NodeJS user in daily life, nor familiar with the pre-commit internal workings. I'm happy to debug further and post more info to help solve this, with some assistance on what to look for next.

Answer (score 1):

I was scratching my head about the very same thing, but with the help of someone on the ESLint Discord, we figured it out.

You need a `package.json` file with the following:

```json
{
    "type": "module",
    "devDependencies": {
        "eslint": "^8.56.0",
        "globals": "^13.24.0"
    }
}
```

Add all the dependencies you need here.

In your GitHub workflow file, you need to add:

```yaml
# Set up Node.js
 - name: Setup Node.js
   uses: actions/setup-node@v4
   with:
     node-version: '20'
 - run: npm install
```

Before you run the `pre-commit` checks.

Hope that help.